# My First Function returns undefined variable ($pageName) error on line #14

Tags: php, function, variables, str-replace

Newb here.

I'm trying to create my first php function which will get the name of the file, stripe out the `'.php'` extension and return a string which is the name of the page file without the `'.php'` file. This if i was using the index page, the title tag would read 'Index'.

To create the function, first i wrote the following process which did what I hoped:

```
$fileName2 = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$pageName2 = str_replace(".php","", $fileName2);
```

However when i try to put it into the context/format of a function i get an error stating:

> NOTICE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: ITC240.PHP ON LINE 14

Here is what i believe to be the relevant code:

**inc_function.php:**

```
function GetPageName($pageName) {
$fileName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$pageName = str_replace('.php','', $fileName);
}
```

I call the function between the title tags:

```
<?php echo GetPageName(); ?>
```

(I tried to put this in code block but every time i put anything in the title tags it didn't print for reasons i don't understand).

Any help or instruction is very much appreciated

Comment: I don't know why, but part of my code isn't showing - trying to resolve this

Comment: I just edited your question because of your missing indents and you overwrote it. I'm not re-editing.

Comment: I've indented it several times - i can't seem to get it all to format - i am on lots of nyQuil though so i'm sure the fault here is all mine. Sorry - i had no way of know you were trying to edit it or were editing it. Sorry

Comment: Add a return before the code to create a code block.

Comment: Everybody deserves a second chance ;-)  I re-edited it. Now just follow what's inside the new edit "IF" you re-edit. @Chezshire

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just had to edit but not do a good enough job, just to force you to do something you said you wouldn't :) Trap successful!

Comment: Nobody "forced" me ;-) Let's hope it "kind of" stays like that ;-) @DarylGill

Comment: Thank you ... Daryl Gill's comment totally confuses me and has nothing to do with this right? I'm a real newb (on nyquil no less) so i'm just a twit now i guess. Thank you I will try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Restructured Answer**

You are being shown an error because your function is looking for data & using the information from your comment *I don't know why but stack overflow kills anything i plop inside title tags: This is what is in the title tags: `<?php echo GetPageName(); ?>`*

So using my best judgement from information provided, I'm assuming you want to have a function to automatically return something with no data specification. In this case, you would need to take note of 2 things

1. The return block in your function will essentially, do as the function says. Return something so it can be used
2. No requirements in your function definition braces

   function TestFunc($RequestedData){ }

the above function definition is asking the developer for information to be provided to the function for data manipulation.

```
function TestFunc(){  }
```

The above function definition is asking for nothing from the developer apart from calling, doing this will enable you to perform exactly what you want.

So, to fix your function:

```
function GetPageName() {
    $fileName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $pageName = str_replace('.php','', $fileName);
    return $pageName;
}
```

---

`var_dumps` to show the power of `return`

Using the exact code above on my local development machine Web Addr of (`http://127.0.0.1)` returns:

> string(5) "index"

Now, using the exact function as specified above, just without the return:

> NULL

Comment: I can't seem to get stackOverflow to allow me to post how i use the code in the title tags which i do like so: <?php echo GetPageName(); ?>

Comment: I thought that once you have the function built, you could then call the function 'echo GetPageName();' which would print to the screen the name of the file that had been processed. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Oh this is Daryl... my process power is in the s**tcan tonight. Looking above now, Thank you.

Comment: @Chezshire Sorry if this is tricky to read, Just edited answer to restructure a to the point answer :)

Comment: Thank you - that solved the current error, now i have a totally new error from having copied and pasted the code (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in... inc_functions.php)

Comment: Hmmms. Still scratching my noggin here, I copied and pasted your function 'GetPageName() {...' into my functions.php file. And pasted '<?php echo $pageName; ?>' in to my title tag and tested. Then tired '<?php echo $pageName; ?>' on my local machine. I'm still getting the undefined var error. Still scratching my head - learned a bit here though so thats cool.

Comment: @Chezshire Are you sure it's caused by the function I have provided. Debugging on my localmachine returns a sucessful function which returns no error

Comment: I'm a newb, but i think i found my problem which was that somewhere in my files, i'm using $pageName already. I changed '$pageName' too '$testVar' and it worked - thank you for your help and patience. I learned a lot, including to keep better track of my variable names. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again Daryl for what you shared with me - I took it and wrote two more functions so i've now successfully written 3 working functions. very empowering day for me!

Answer (score 1):

to get only the name of the file use :

```
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
```

Comment: I don't know why but stack overflow kills anything i plop inside title tags: This is what is in the title tags: <?php echo GetPageName(); ?>

Comment: I tried this, but it produced the same error message 'Undefined Variable'.